# R is using multiple threads with no job running (R v4.0/Win 10.018363)

Tags: r, rstudio, cpu-usage

A few days ago I noticed R was using 34% of the CPU when I have no code running. I noticed it again today and I can't figure out why. If I restart R, CPU usage returns to normal, then after 20 minutes or so it ramps up again.

I have a task scheduled that downloads a small file once a week using R, and another using wget in ubuntu (WSL). It might be the case that the constant CPU usage only happens after I download covid-related data from a github (link below). Is there a way to see if this is hijacking resources? If it is, other people should know about it.

I don't think it's a windows task reporting error since my temps are what I would expect for a constant 34% cpu usage (~56C).

[image: CPU usage]

Is this a security issue? Is there a way to see what R is doing? I'm sure there is a way to better inspect this but I don't know where to begin.. Glasswire hasn't reported any unusual activity.

From Win10 event viewer, I've noticed a lot of these recently but don't quite know how to read it:

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID  {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}  and APPID  {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}  to the user redacted SID (S-1-5-21-1564340199-2159526144-420669435-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (S-1-15-2-181400768-2433568983-420332673-1010565321-2203959890-2191200666-700592917). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

*edit: CPU usage seems to be positively correlated with the duration R is open.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you provided, it looks like RStudio (not R) is using a lot of resources. R and RStudio are 2 very different things. These types of issues are very difficult to investigate as one need to be able to reproduce them on another computer. One thing you can maybe do is raise the issue on github to the RStudio team.

Comment: Good point about the distinction!  I should have caught it. D'oh!

Comment: The issue was related to the Rstudio version. I upgraded Rstudio to the preview version and the errant CPU creep went away.